# Why check if child exists in Firebase always return false?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my application, I use below code to check if the child message exists or not.

```
this.firechats.child(uid).child(touid).orderByChild("time").startAt(time).on('value', (snapshot) => {
       var temp = snapshot.val();
       for (var tempkey in temp) {
         console.log("new message exists")
         console.log(temp[tempkey].message);
       }
       console.log(snapshot.hasChild("message"))
       if(snapshot.child("message").exists()){
            //do something
       }
    });
```

In fact there is a message "hello", the log output also print it out, but the check function always returns false. What is wrong?

```
new message exists
hello
false
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snapshot` contains immediate children which are the push IDs of the messages that were added there.  So you can expect `snapshot.child('-Lp_cm...')` to exist.  If you want the message of *that* child, you would have to go one deeper: `snapshot.child('-Lp_cm...').child('message')`

It sounds like you actually want to iterate the list of messages in the snapshot, similar to the way you are doing with `for (var tempkey in temp)`, then dig into those snapshots' children.